# How do I select 2 distinct columns using structured references in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can i use a structured reference in excel to select just 2 columns from the below table? e.g. Show only Column 1 and Column 4.

I understand that to get columns 1 through for I can use =ExampleTable[[Column 1]:[Column 4]] but I dont know what to do for just column 1 and column 4.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Second | Third | Fourth |
| 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 4th |

So the question is what format from above just gets me column 1 and for

=ExampleTable[[Column 1]????[Column 4]]

| Column 1 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- |
| First | Fourth |
| 1st | 4th |

Edit -- I want to apply this within a filter

Comment: I don't think you can do that using just structured references; I believe you'll need a formula that refers to the columns. eg `=CHOOSECOLS(Table1[#All],1,4)` or one of the other options in the below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=HSTACK(Table3[Column 1],Table3[Column 4])
```

where 'Table3` is your table name.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Filter:  `=FILTER(Table1[#All],{1,0,0,1})`

[image]

You could even put checkboxes above each column and attach the Filter to the results of those checkboxes:
[image]
(ok, not the answer to the question but wasn't sure if it would work).